# datagridview paint line also when selecting the cell of the current line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a snippet of code but it doesn't work very well, why?

1 - When starting the application, it is painting all records pink, only when I select all painted that it works normally again.

2 - When selecting two or more cells and then selecting only one of the selected cells, the painting of the line fails.

I would like to paint the entire line of the selected cell with the property selecionMode = CellSelect and multiSelect = true, so that when I select one or several cells, I paint the corresponding lines.
[what i want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ39O.gif)

```
private void DataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
            var dataGrid = (DataGridView)sender; 
            var s = e.StateChanged;// = DataGridViewElementStates.Selected;
            if (e.Cell.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGrid.Rows[e.Cell.RowIndex];
                if (e.Cell.Selected)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                }
                else if (!e.Cell.Selected)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that all rows are selected when loading the data, which simply selects all rows from the included data. At this time, There is no "unselect" and so it paints all lines.

I solved the case in the following way:

Disabling the grid before loading data:

```
dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

During the line painting process, I validate if the grid is enabled, to know that it is at the time of loading the data:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = e.StateChanged;// = DataGridViewElementStates.Selected;
        if (e.Cell.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.Cell.RowIndex];
            if ((e.Cell.Selected) && ((DataGridView)sender).Enabled)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
            }
            else if (!e.Cell.Selected)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

At the end, I enable the grid again in the "dataGridView1_Paint" event:

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

**An important detail** is that the "Paint" event is invoked all the time, making it impossible for the grid to be disabled later if necessary within the business model. If there is no such possibility, the flow will work perfectly. It was the only way I found.

Comment: that's what is happening, but I can't succeed in this solution, because leaving a property unusable is not viable, but thanks for responding and making this clear.

Comment: I don't understand, which property is unusable?
The grid will be enabled normally, what you will not be able to do is disable the grid at runtime, it will always be enabled.